# In Visual Studio Code, how can I efficiently tweak Pyplot figures?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

Often I need to optimize a complex plot in many iterations, an example would be finding a good position for the legend. Let's say my code looks something like this:

```
def main()

    ...

    plot(x, y)


def plot(data, legends)

    fig, ax = subplots(1,2)
    
    ...

    ax[0].legend(frameon=False,loc="lower right")
```

Now I need to run the last line multiple times with different locations and look at the resulting figure. Currently, how I do this would be to set a breakpoint after that last line, start debugging until it pauses at the breakpoint, and then I will iteratively run `ax[0].legend()` with different arguments followed by `fig.savefig(path)` in the debug console. The result can be seen in an image viewer. Is there a quicker, "real time" way to do this task? Is there a VS Code shortcut for "Run selected code in Debug Console" maybe? Edit: it is possible to assign this shortcut, its name in the list of key bindings is *Evaluate in Debug Console*.

Comment: Could you please give us an example to describe your needs in detail? For the _"Run selected code in Debug Console"_ you said, have you used the shortcut key "Shift+Enter" (or right-click and select "Run Selection/line in Python Terminal")?

Comment: @JillCheng "Shift+Enter" does not work here because I'm running a part of a method, not a script. But I assigned a key binding to "Evaluate in Debug Console" and am quite happy with it so far.